# JFreechart, Line Chart with filled Areas

Tags: java, graph, charts, jfreechart

I am trying to create chart like below:

[image: Sample Chart - Requirement]

While I've almost achieved everything by simply creating a line chart and customizing shape/paint for Renderer, I can't seem to find a way to fill the areas under the series line.

Any clues, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your chart with a [`StackedXYAreaRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/StackedXYAreaRenderer.html). Specify `AREA_AND_SHAPES` in the constructor and enable outlines. See the `ChartFactory` code for [`createStackedXYAreaChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1846) as an example.

```
StackedXYAreaRenderer r = new StackedXYAreaRenderer(XYAreaRenderer.AREA_AND_SHAPES);
r.setOutline(true);
```

Given a renderer, you can set the outline paint and stroke as desired.

Comment: I'll definitely give this a try and revert back.

Comment: How to make the StackedXYAreaChart display DAY in x-axis? the dataset seems to accept only XYSeries that leaves no option apparently to specify Date/String for X-Axis

Comment: Use `setDateFormatOverride()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20setDateFormatOverride).

Comment: @ask-dev Could you provide a code snippet of your final work?